# jQuery object vs htmlString

Tags: javascript, jquery

html segment:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="one">Div #1</div>
    <div id="two">Div #2</div>
</div>
```

if I set $p as a jQuery object, as below:

```
$p = $('<p>whatever you like</p>');
//$p = '<p>whatever you like</p>';
$('#one').after($p);
$('#two').after($p);
```

then the result would be:

```
Div #1
Div #2
whatever you like
```

While I set $p as htmlString, as below:

```
//$p = $('<p>whatever you like</p>');
$p = '<p>whatever you like</p>';
$('#one').after($p);
$('#two').after($p);
```

then the result would be:

```
Div #1
whatever you like
Div #2
whatever you like
```

Seems while I use object, jQuery doesn't clone the object, but just move it; while I use htmlString, it create a new object accordingly each time.

I want to know the exact reason. It would be more appreciated if any reference could be provided as well.

Many thanks!

Comment: **object vs htmlString** is a wrong comparison. An object is always an object but a string may create objects if you put tags in it and it doesnt mean you can reference those objects using that string

Answer (score 2):

> Seems while I use object, jQuery doesn't clone the object, but just move it; while I use htmlString, it create a new object accordingly each time.

Correct. The first time you call `after`, you put the elements inside the jQuery object into the DOM. The second time, they get *moved*. This is the standard DOM behavior.

It's documented, somewhat indirectly, on [the `after` page](http://api.jquery.com/after/):

> If an element selected this way is inserted into a single location elsewhere in the DOM, it will be moved rather than cloned:

This echoes the standard behavior of the DOM methods [`appendChild`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-184E7107) and [`insertBefore`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-952280727).

Note that if you call `after` on a jQuery set that has *multiple* elements in it, the elements you're passing in will get *moved* to after the first target element and then *cloned* to go after the remaining target elements:

> **Important**: If there is more than one target element, however, cloned copies of the inserted element will be created for each target except for the last one.

[Example](http://jsbin.com/puhujuja/1)

This second behavior is jQuery-specific (although with sufficient hand-waving one might argue it's similar to how the DOM handles document fragments and, on more modern browsers, template elements).

Answer (score 1):

When $p is a string `'<p>whatever you like</p>'`  and you append it using `.after()`, the string is added to the HTML. It's never a jQuery object.

When $p is a jQuery object `$('<p>whatever you like</p>');` and you're appending it using one of the append functions like `.after()` you're moving it around the page. If you don't want to move it, clone it.

```
$('#one').after($p.clone());
$('#two').after($p.clone());
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gVHsP/)**